# Por que los media querys de mi proyecto no funcionan como deberían?

Tags: responsive, mediaqueries

En Codepen funciona perfecto para si intento subir mi pagina a GitHub o incluso en el servidor local intento verlos con las herramientas para desarrolladores de Chrome y los `media querys` no funcionan como deberian.

Cuando digo que los `media querys` no funcionan me refiero a que el proyecto lo empecé `Mobile First` y el layout cambia a partir de una pantalla superior a 500px. Sin embargo, el proyecto se ve siempre como si la pantalla fuese superior a 500px. Es decir, definitivamente, esta reconociendo el media query. De lo contrario se vería como en la versión Mobile pero no reconoce el **break point** para volver a la versión Mobile.

**Adjunto el repositorio **

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    body {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        display: flex;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
    }

    h2,
    h1 + p {
        font-size: 1.75rem;
    }

    .intro,
    .main-content {
        width: 50%;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .main-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

Como explico arriba lo que se imprime en pantalla es esa versión del layout, es decir la versión desktop que construí con los media querys. 
Pero no toma el **break point** de 500px para volver a la versión mobile. 
Al menos no el servidor local pero si en la plataforma CodePen.
**Adjunto el HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flyer for a BBQ webinar!</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Learn how to make <strong>the best BBQ ribs</strong> in town</h1>
            <p>Join us for this live webinar</p>
            <p class="top-text">Mouthwateringly delicious</p>
        </div>

        <div class="main-content">
            <h2>Become a BBQ master! </h2>
            <p>Register Today</p>
            <p>BBQ isn't just standing in front of your grill with it on full blast and hoping for the best. It's an art! One way to speed up the process is to learn from the best. You can do just that by signing up for this free webinar!</p>

            <form class="email-collector" action="#" method="POST">
                <input type="text" required placeholder="first name">
                <input type="email" required  placeholder="email">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
            </form>

            <p class="fine-print">We'll never share your information without your permission</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) y añade el código que has intentado para ayudar a quien pueda contestarte. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y conseguir tu primera medalla.

Comment: Holaa Lucia. Puedo incluir el código pero a qué te refieres con problemas de formato?

Comment: Ups, fallo mío, copié y pegué y eso se me pasó!

Comment: Por favor considera editar y agregar aquí el código mínimo necesario para reproducir tu ejemplo

Comment: A lo que se refería el compañero @Aprendiz a que este tipo de problemas con **CSS** es mucho más fácil verlos en funcionamiento. Para ello, además del **CSS** que nos adjuntas, es necesario tener el **HTML**. Este sitio, tiene una herramienta muy útil dentro del editor de preguntas/respuestas al que llamamos "snniped" y que te permite ejecutar **HTML**, **CSS** o **Javascript** para poder verlo directamente desde aquí. Puedes usarla desde el botón que tiene apariencia de página con un símbolo de "mayor que" y otro de "menor que" dentro y con el título "fragmento JavaScript/HTML/CSS".

Comment: Ok! Disculpen! Es la primera vez que hago una pregunta en esta plataforma. Gracias por su paciencia y sus indicaciones!